# How do I use Scale for Application-only windows?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

If I have 3 windows opened in the same application (e.g Google Chrome) I get this in the Unity Bar:

[image: 3 open windows in Google Chrome]

OK, that's good and expected. If I click that, it will Scale **the windows that belong to that application**, like this:

[image: 3 scaled open windows in Google Chrome]

Great! That's what I want to achieve more often by using **hot corners**. I did that with TopLeft and *Scale All Windows*, like this:

[image: All scaled windows]

**How can I achieve the scale of only the application windows (like Chrome) with a hot corner** (like TopRight)? I've already tried "Initiate Window Picker for Window Group" but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Using Ubuntu 12.04 and the Scale / Scale Addons plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [bug 774059](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/774059) on Launchpad.

Comment: This is the "answer" (it should be possible, but it isn't because of a bug). Let's all hope someone fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the scale plugin to only scale Chrome windows you will have to open CCSM which I assume you have installed already. Then go to the scale plug in. Click on the Behaviour tab then where it has "Scale Windows" and a bunch of types you will have to clear that field and then enter:

> class=Google-chrome

In that field. Then the scale plugin will only effect Google Chrome windows, However you will lose the ability to scale all other windows using your hot corner/keystroke.
If you don't like the changes you can hit the X button on the far right side by the "Scale Windows" dialogue box.

Comment: Yup, already installed CCSM. The thing is that, as I stated, I need both hot corners (all applications and application windows). Using `class=Google-chrome` would wreck that. It's worth noticing that I want the functionality for *all* the application windows, not some specified. Google Chrome was just an example.

Comment: AH okay I understand what you are saying. I don't think that is possible with Compiz, unless you somehow had multiple copies of the scale plug-in. I was thinking if there was a Window match type for open or active/focusses windows, you could set it to active and similar, but according to the Compiz Wiki there is not. http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching